# How to set up python cron job in app engine from september to may

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I want to set up a cron job for sending out weekly emails from september to may. What I have so far for cron.yaml:

```
- description: mail
  url: /crontask
  schedule: every monday 09:00  ["from" (first Monday of September) "to" (last Monday of May)]
```

app.yaml:

```
- url: /.*
  script: myapp.application
```

python:

```
class CronTask(Handler):
    def post(self):
        *send out mail*
```

python mapping:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                    ('/crontask', CronTask)...
```

What is the proper "from" "to" syntax for this?

Comment: does from september to may not work?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this handler is called once per week.  What if you check the date in the CronTask handler using Python's datetime library instead of specifying it on the crontab?

Alternatively, from the documentation "The brackets are for illustration only, and quotes indicate a literal.", so don't use those brackets and quotes.  A line that works might look something like:

```
schedule: every monday of sep,oct,nov,dec,jan,feb,mar,apr,may 17:00
```